# PowerShell Group-Object no longer splitting objects into fixed-size collections

Tags: powershell, scope, group-object

I had this in a script which I believe was working well, but appears to have stopped working:

```
$testList = @("object 1","object 2","object 3","object 4","object 5")
$counter = 0
$maxSize = 2
$groupedList = $testList | Group-Object { [math]::Floor($counter++ / $maxSize) }
$groupedList
$groupedList | Measure-Object
```

Previously Measure-Object would have given me a Count of 3, but now I receive a count of 1.

Why is this no longer working? Is the counter integer not being incremented within the Group-Object command anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your command ever worked as intended (see the bottom section for details).

Replace:

```
{ [math]::Floor($counter++ / $maxSize) }
```

with:

```
{ [math]::Floor((Get-Variable -Scope 1 counter).Value++ / $maxSize) }
```

in order to ensure that it is the *caller*'s `$counter` variable that is updated across invocations of the script block.

Note:

- `$script:counter++` works too, but only if the calling scope is a script's top-level scope.
- [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) `-Scope 1 counter` explicitly targets the parent scope's definition of `$counter`, which is the caller's; for brevity you could omit `-Scope 1`, because by default a variable in the closest ancestral scope is returned.
- [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests **another option**:

  - You can define your `$counter` variable as *a reference-type object with a `.Value` property* rather than as an integer, in the simplest form as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables):

    ```
    $counter = @{ Value = 0 }
    ```
  - By virtue of `$counter` now containing an *object reference*, the child scope in the script block sees the very same object when *querying* the value of the parent scope's `$counter` variable, and can update its `.Value` property:

    ```
    { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $maxSize) }
    ```

---

The problem is that the script block passed to the (positionally) implied `-Property` parameter of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) runs in a *child* scope, so that `$counter++` implicitly creates a *block-local* variable on every invocation:

- That is, `$counter++` does *not* act on the existing variable in the parent scope; it implicitly creates a scope-local *copy* of the `$counter` variable (with the caller's current value), and `++` is applied to *it*.

  - This perhaps surprising behavior - a *local* variable implicitly getting created when (ostensibly) *assigning* to a variable that exists in an ancestral scope - is discussed in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403663/45375).
  - On a related note, it may be surprising that such a script block (which includes calculated properties in general) runs in a child scope rather than directly in the caller's to begin with - see [GitHub issue #7157](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157)
- Since your `++` is a *post*-increment, it is the original `0` value (copied from the parent-scope variable) that acts as the LHS operand to the division operation `/`.
- On exiting the script block, the local `$counter` variable goes out of scope, and the next invocation starts from scratch.

Thus, in effect, the script block's return value is a fixed `0`, so you'll only ever get *one* group.

---

**Alternatives to using `Group-Object` for "chunking"**:

Your use of `Group-Object` to achieve "chunking" (batching, partitioning, i.e. splitting the input into arrays of fixed size) is elegant, but ultimately inefficient, and it isn't a *streaming* solution, because all input must be collected up front (neither aspect may matter in a given situation).

- It would be great if [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) directly supported such a feature, which is what [GitHub issue #8270](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8270) proposes, in the form of a `-ReadCount` parameter:

  ```
  # WISHFUL THINKING
  PS> 1..5 | Select-Object -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object { "$_" }
  1 2
  3 4
  5
  ```
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289500/45375) provides a custom function, `Select-Chunk`, which implements this functionality:

  ```
  # Assumes function Select-Chunk from the linked answer is defined.
  PS> 1..5 | Select-Chunk -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object { "$_" }
  1 2
  3 4
  5
  ```

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @DickyMoore, and I appreciate the nice feedback.